# Работа с модулями python 2/3

Tags: python, импорт

У меня есть путь **/module/invisible/module1/module2/echo.py** я хочу импортировать этот модуль я вызываю метод `from`:

```
from module.invisible.module1.module2.echo import function_
```

**Я не использую class , а просто делаю все в def .**
У меня пишет: `ImportError: No module named module.invisble.module1.module2.echo`
Как мне импортировать модуль в таком далеком каталоге?

Comment: Каждый перечисленный каталог сам по себе должен являться модулем, это так?

Comment: @andreymal нет, модуль только последний файл echo все остальное это папки.

Comment: А должны быть модулями, вот

Comment: @andreymal так, а если мне надо из папки импортировать модуль в которой ещё 10 папок и в конце лежит мой модуль, что мне делать?

Comment: Все папки по пути к модулю должны сами быть модулями, чтобы из папки сделать модуль надо внутри неё создать файл `__init__.py` (можно пустой)

Comment: @andreymal тоесть в каждой папки создать такой модуль? И что в него записывать тогда? или ничего не надо

Comment: Ничего не надо записывать, просто создайте файл, но еще может быть проблема с локацией, попробуйте указать путь из дествительной директории, добавив точку `.` таким образом `from .module.invisible.module1.module2.echo import function_`

Comment: @IgorSergeevich спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения, это создать в папке с python.exe файл мой_файл.pth.
Внутри файла нужно указать путь к вашему модулю, на примере с виндоус:
    `C:/module/invisible/module1/module2/`

В файле с вашей программой теперь уже можно обращаться просто:
`import echo`

Comment: мне это не нужно

Comment: @you have no pass, это один из стандартных способов работы с модулями. Разве это не решает вашу задачу?

Comment: нет, я же сказал мне надо из каталога импортировать модуль, с вашей идее так не сработает потому что каталогов у меня может быть и 10. И я не хочу закидывать именно в папку с питоном

Comment: @you have no pass, такие длинные пути импорта, это очень плохой способ.

Comment: у меня конечно всего 2 вложения, я же не хочу чтоб у меня все файлы лежали в оной папки, надо их как-то отсоритировать

Comment: @you have no pass, в .pth файлы, можно сколько угодно путей добавлять. Хоть сотню.

Comment: @you have no pass, на практике вы делаете модуль "мои_библиотеки", путь к которому вы прописываете в pth файле или окружении python, и уже от него импортируете: `from мои_библиотеки import моя_библиотека `